# Not able to alert/access the changed id after cloning

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

My code is :

```
var draggedElement = this.template.querySelector("[id='"+divId+"']");
                      
var cln = draggedElement.cloneNode(true,true);
cln.classList.add('completed'); 
cln.classList.add('box-height'); 
cln.id='clone-'+divId;             

event.target.appendChild(cln);
```

Now if I want to alert the event target id on the onclick event it gives empty result.

Trying to use like this but did not work.

```
 const btn = this.template.querySelector("[id='clone-"+divId+"']");

 btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    console.log(event.target.id);

  });
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you console.log(draggedElement, btn, event.target)?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably binding the event handler before the dragged element is created (which I suppose is done in response of a user action).

Instead of playing with `id` attributes, just bind the event handler at the moment you add the cloned element to the document. At that time you have the reference to the cloned element, so you can just add the event listener to it.

Little, simplified, demo:

```js
var draggedElement = document.querySelector("#test");
                      
var cln = draggedElement.cloneNode(true,true);
cln.removeAttribute("id"); // Don't use `id`
cln.textContent = "cloned " + cln.textContent;
document.body.appendChild(cln);
cln.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log('Cloned button Clicked');
});
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
```

#### Event Delegation

Although I would strongly advise against using dynamically generated `id` attributes, if you really require to identify elements by such `id` attributes, then use event delegation:

```js
setTimeout(function () { // In reality this would be some drag event handler
  var draggedElement = document.querySelector("#test");

  var cln = draggedElement.cloneNode(true,true);
  cln.id = "cloned-" + cln.id; // Bad practice
  cln.textContent = "cloned " + cln.textContent;
  document.body.appendChild(cln);
}, 500);

// Event delegation
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if (event.target.id = "cloned-test") {
        console.log('Cloned button Clicked');
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="test">test</button>
```

Comment: Yes only getting the button click alert is working in my code too but I need to access the event target id. Thanks for your response but I am searching for something else.

Comment: That is quite a restrictive requirement. Producing `id` attributes dynamically is a code smell. There is always a better way to do things.

Comment: Anyway, added a section to my answer (reluctantly).

Comment: Thanks I will try this one, I also did by again calling the querySelector on id and making it variable able to use inside my function.